# Tensorflow dense layer operation

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, tensor

```
a = tf.random_uniform([5, 3, 5])
b = tf.random_uniform([5, 1, 6])

tiled_b = tf.tile(b, [1, 3, 1])
c = tf.concat([a, tiled_b], 2)
d = tf.layers.dense(c, 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

Here the output shape turned out to be `5x3x10`. The input shape is `5x3x11`. I've seen the source code of this operation and found that the weights matrix is of shape `11x10`. I also understand that the operation is similar to `res = np.tensordot(input,weights,axes=([2],[0]))`. What I don't understand is how this is happening. How do I visualize this operation in a neural network? Since, the dense layer is just a single layer with 10 neurons, how can the weight matrix be `11x10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a dense layer every input channel is connected to each output neuron with a weight. So here `input_channel=11` and `ouput_channel=10`, so number of weights `11x10`.

```
# input 5x3x11, here last dimension is the input channel
dense_layer_weight_shape = [input_channel, output_channel]
```

Comment: How is each neuron connected to an input channel? Are you saying that each neuron is shared by the `5x3` matrix? If so, what is the operation that's happening?

Comment: Each of the `5x3` groups contains `10` output neurons. In the input, there are `5x3` groups of `11` input neurons. So in each of these `5x3` groups, that set of `11` is multiplied by a matrix to get a set of `10`.